# Run function after animation is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried give callback function (FUNCTIONX) in .animate(), but it fires immediately - and doesn't waiting for animation end.

```
nav.click(function () {
    holder.stop(true, true);
    var target = $(this).attr('class');

    if (target === 'right') {
        var value = current.width();
        holder.animate({
            right: '+=' + value
        }, slideSpeed, FUNCTIONX());
        current = current.next();
    } else {
        var value = current.prev().width();
        holder.animate({
            right: '-=' + value
        }, slideSpeed, FUNCTIONX());
        current = current.prev();
    }
});
```

Also tried with .promise() (as below) with same effect.

```
        var value = current.width();
        holder.animate({
            right: '+=' + value
        }, slideSpeed);
        current = current.next();
        nav.promise().done(function() {
          alert( 'dupa' );
        });
```

How run function after this animation is completed, after slide effect ends?

Comment: Instead of this: `nav.promise().done(function...` do this `holder.promise().done(function...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FUNCTIONX is called immediately here. Try removing `()`.

From:

```
holder.animate({
  right: '+=' + value
}, slideSpeed, FUNCTIONX());
```

To:

```
holder.animate({
  right: '+=' + value
}, slideSpeed, FUNCTIONX);
```